# Arduino Code for Juggling Machine (Stepper Motors)

Tags: c++, arduino

I have built a machine that juggles. An Arduino sends signals to stepper motor drivers that drive NEMA 23 size stepper motors.

[image: juggling machine]

Video of the machine: https://youtu.be/-9zD_8erkck

Currently, each arm makes one revolution and then pauses while the other arm makes one revolution. One arm starts before the other arm comes to a complete stop, the amount of overlap is captured by the variable `stepover`.

I would like to make the machine more consistent and run quieter with less vibration. How can I make it run smoother? Is there a way to do this where the hands will never come to a complete stop?

The stepper motors are running at 800 steps per revolution. I have tried to using more steps/rev for smoother operation, but the `accelstepper` library will not run the motors fast enough.

I have tried altering the values `max_acceleration`, `max_speed`, and `stepover`. I have not found a way to optimize these values.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
AccelStepper stepper1(AccelStepper::DRIVER, 9, 8);
AccelStepper stepper2(AccelStepper::DRIVER, 4, 3);

int start = 0;
int side = 0;
int max_speed = 6000;
int max_acceleration = 12000;
int stepover = 300;
int step_distance = 800;

void setup()
{
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(max_speed);
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(max_speed);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(1234);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(1234);
  stepper1.moveTo(600);
  stepper2.moveTo(-200);
}

void loop()
{
  // This code gets the arms in the right place before startup
  if (start == 0) {
    while (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) != 0) {
      stepper1.run();
    }
    while (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) != 0) {
      stepper2.run();
    }
    start = 1;
    stepper1.setAcceleration(max_acceleration);
    stepper2.setAcceleration(max_acceleration);
    delay(500);
  }

  // This code moves the left arm
  if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) == 0
      and abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < stepover
      and side == 0) {
    stepper1.moveTo(step_distance + stepper1.currentPosition());
    side = 1;
  }

  // This code moves the right arm
  if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) == 0
      and abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < stepover
      and side == 1) {
    stepper2.setCurrentPosition(0);
    stepper2.moveTo(step_distance);
    side = 0;
  }

  if (start == 1) {
    stepper2.run();
    stepper1.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: How many steps are available on the motor? Some datasheets I found seem to indicate 200 steps / revolution. Do you have a model with 800 steps? If it fits in memory, you could create an array, defining the desired speed for each step position. Your current logic would be something like `uint8_t speed[800] = {255, 255, 255, ... 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...., 0};`, either full speed or full stop. You could try to find the correct profile, and modify the values so that the motors is never completely stopping.

Comment: I am using stepper motors drivers that are capable of between 200 and 6400 steps per revolution. Computing the speeds and accelerations was too difficult for me, so I used the accelstepper library as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `loop`, you're checking if some code should be run before startup. You could simply move the corresponding code to `setup`, and be sure it's only run once:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
AccelStepper stepper1(AccelStepper::DRIVER, 9, 8);
AccelStepper stepper2(AccelStepper::DRIVER, 4, 3);

int side = 0;
int max_speed = 6000;
int max_acceleration = 12000;
int stepover = 300;
int step_distance = 800;

void setup() {
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(max_speed);
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(max_speed);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(1234);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(1234);
  stepper1.moveTo(600);
  stepper2.moveTo(-200);

  while (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) > 0) {
    stepper1.run();
  }
  while (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) > 0) {
    stepper2.run();
  }
  stepper1.setAcceleration(max_acceleration);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(max_acceleration);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // This code moves the left arm
  if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) == 0 and abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < stepover and side == 0) {
    stepper1.moveTo(step_distance + stepper1.currentPosition());
    side = 1;
  }

  // This code moves the right arm
  if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) == 0 and abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < stepover and side == 1) {
    stepper2.setCurrentPosition(0);
    stepper2.moveTo(step_distance);
    side = 0;
  }

  stepper2.run();
  stepper1.run();
}
```

- `abs` cannot be negative, so it might be clearer to replace `abs(...) != 0` by `abs(...) > 0`
- `AccelStepper::move(long relative)` is defined as `moveTo(_currentPos + relative);` so you can probably replace your `moveTo` by `move`.